# How to call a Route/Render an ejs page from an External Javascript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

I am facing a difficulty in using AJAX in my project.

I am having a Date input field in my ejs file where i am calling a external function (in seperate JS file) during onchange event as follows,

```
<input id="confbookdate" type="date" onchange="confDateChange('<%= conferenceRoom.id %>', '<%=conferenceRoom.name %>')" required></input>
```

I am passing 2 parameters to the function as above,

onchange="confDateChange('<%= conferenceRoom.id %>', '<%=conferenceRoom.name %>')"

In the external JS file, the function is as follows,

```
function confDateChange(id, name){
    $.get("/conf/book/"+id+"/"+name, function(data){
        console.log(data);
        debugger
    });
}
```

I am fetching some data records from the MongoDB when the GET Route is called (in app.js file) and the result is coming in the data.

Now i need to use this data in my ejs file. Need to check some conditions and display the result in my ejs file.

How to pass this result data from the external js file to the ejs file ??

I couldn't able to find any solution for this :-(

Comment: you are using EJS on server side ?

Comment: No, I am using ejs on client side. Instead of a HTML page, using ejs.

Comment: if you're fetcing data with AJAX, use jquery or vanilla JS to manipulate DOM, insert the data where you want